# Unit rabbitmq-server.service could not be found

Tags: django, redis, rabbitmq, celery

I run the following commands on Ubuntu 20.04

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
sudo systemctl enable rabbitmq-server
sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server
systemctl status rabitmq-server
```

and I get this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qubF4.png)

Unit rabbitmq-server.service could not be found.

I got a similar problem using redis, both locally and on heroku. Please help me.

Comment: [I also receive this error when connecting to heroku redis :      2021-04-11 19:58:44,253: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://:**@ec2-54-217-183-159.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:22600//: Error while reading from socket: (104, 'Connection reset by peer').
Trying again in 26.00 seconds... (13/100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last command has a typo - it should be `systemctl status rabbitmq-server` (your command was missing one 'b').